# Ring of Integers as a sum of Ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I can't understand why $\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1} + \mathfrak{p}_i = \mathfrak{O} \implies \alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1} + \mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{O}$ in the proof of the following statement:

> If $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$ are two non-zero Ideals of $\mathfrak{O}$, the Ring of Integers of a Field, there exists $a \in \mathfrak{a}$ such that:
> $$\alpha \mathfrak{a}^{-1}+ \mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{O}$$
> We first notice that $\alpha \in \mathfrak{a} \implies \alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$ is an Ideal of $\mathfrak{O}$ and $\mathfrak{a}|\langle\alpha\rangle$ and $\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1} + \mathfrak{b}$ is the gcd of both. Therefore, it is sufficient to choose $\alpha$ such that: $$\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1} + \mathfrak{p}_i = \mathfrak{O} \quad \forall_{i \in \{1,\cdots,r\}}$$
> For $\mathfrak{p}_i$, the prime ideals of $\mathfrak{b}$. 
> ...

It being the greatest common divisor, means that it is the smallest ideal, that contains both $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the situation is the following let $K|\mathbb{Q}$ be a finite extension and $\mathfrak{O}=\mathfrak{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$. Then as you (probably) know $\mathfrak{O}$ is a Dedekind domain, hence every ideal of $\mathfrak{O}$ decomposes uniquely into a product of prime ideals of $\mathfrak{O}$ and the group of fractional ideals of $K$ is the free group generated by the prime ideals of $\mathfrak{O}$.

Let $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}\subset \mathfrak{O}$ be two ideals then we have  unique decompositions$$\mathfrak{a} = \prod_\mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{p}^{v_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{a})},\quad \mathfrak{b}=\prod_\mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{p}^{v_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{b})}$$
where $\mathfrak{p}$ runs over all prime ideals of $\mathfrak{O}$.
We set $\gcd(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b})=\prod_\mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{p}^{\min(v_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{a}),v_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{b}))}$ and this coincides with $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}$.

We want to show $$\alpha \mathfrak{a}^{-1}+\mathfrak{b} = \gcd(\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1},\mathfrak{b})=\mathfrak{O}.$$
By the definition of $\gcd$ this means nothing but that $\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ have no common prime divisors but this means that every prime divisor $\mathfrak{p}_i$ of $\mathfrak{b}$ is not a prime divisor of $\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$ i.e. that $\gcd(\mathfrak{p}_i, \alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1})=\mathfrak{O}$ which says that $\mathfrak{p}_i+\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1}=\mathfrak{O}$.

Here is a justification for $\gcd(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b})=\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}$: by definition the RHS is the smallest ideal containing $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$ so by definition the LHS contains the RHS. Now take any ideal $\mathfrak{c}$ containing $\mathfrak{b},\mathfrak{a}$. Then $\mathfrak{c}$ divides the latter two ideals. Let's write $\mathfrak{c}=\prod_\mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{p}^{e_\mathfrak{p}}$ where $e_\mathfrak{p}$ are positive integers and almost all are zero. Then we get for any prime $\mathfrak{p}$ $$\mathfrak{p}^{e_\mathfrak{p}} \supset \mathfrak{c} \supset \mathfrak{a} $$ so $\mathfrak{p}^{e_\mathfrak{p}}$ divides $\mathfrak{a}$. Writing $\mathfrak{a}$ in its unique prime decomposition we see $e_\mathfrak{p}\le v_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{a})$ and by an analogous argument we get $e_\mathfrak{p}\le v_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{b})$ and so $e_\mathfrak{p}\le \min(v_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{b}),v_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{a}))$. This shows the claim.

Comment: I might be tired, but isn't that the converse $\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1} + \mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{O} \implies \forall_i \mathfrak{p}_i + \alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1} = \mathfrak{O}$ ? ($\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1} + \mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{O} \iff \alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ have no common prime divisors $\implies$ every prime divisor $\mathfrak{p}_i$ of $\mathfrak{b}$ is not a prime divisor of $\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1} \iff \text{gcd}(\mathfrak{p}_i,\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1}) = \mathfrak{O} \forall_i \implies \mathfrak{p}_i + \alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1} = \mathfrak{O} \forall_i$)

Comment: You should *justify* why "this coincides with $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}$" since that is the heart of the question.

Comment: @Pastudent If every prime divisor $\mathbb{q}$ of $\mathfrak{b}$ does not occur in $\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$ i.e. iff $\gcd(\mathfrak{q},\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1})=\mathfrak{O}$ then we get that $\gcd(\mathfrak{b},\alpha\mathfrak{a}^{-1})=\mathfrak{O}$ by definition because all the exponents in the definition of gcd are $=0$.